# How to prevent Gulp output buffering

Tags: node.js, gulp

Gulp seems to somehow buffer output, meaning that if I have `console.log()` at the beginning of my task, then some long-running operation in it and `console.log()` after it finished, both logs will be shown in the console at the same time (at the end of the task).

First question: **is this behavior expected** or is there possibly something wrong with my setup?

Second: **can I force Gulp / Node to print to console as soon as it reaches the `console.log()` statement**?

Comment: Hi @borek. No, I didn't see any place in the code where Gulp would temper with `console.log` behavior. I wrote a simple case and it's not failing (it prints at the beginning and at the end). Can you post your use case?

Comment: Hm, just tried another, fresh script and indeed there seems to be no output buffering. Will delete this question in a few hours.

Answer (score 0):

Gulp does not buffer output. The generally tasks run asynchronously, though, so your `console.log` output may not show up where you expect it to.